# JQuery click event fires on second click but not on first in search form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do my search form and use Jquery. So it works, it shows me result, but ONLY on the second time. When I click it on the first time - it shows all blocks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#search').click(function () {
    text = $('#search_word').val();
    $(".return").fadeIn('slow');
    $('.topic_retain:contains("' + text + '")').css("display", "block");
    $('.question_block:contains("' + text + '")').fadeIn();
});

$(".go_back").click(function(){
        $('.search_topic').fadeIn();
});    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" id="search_word"><button 
id="search">Search</button>
<div class="return"><span class="go_back">Go Back</span></div>
    
    <div class="topic_retain">
        <h1>Retain</h1>
        <div class="question_block">
            <div class="question"><span class="q">First question</span></div>
            <div class="answer">First answer.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="question_block">
            <div class="question"><span class="q">Second question</span></div>
            <div class="answer">Second question</div>
        </div>
        <div class="question_block">
            <div class="question"><span class="q">Third question</span></div>
            <div class="answer">Third answer.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `.return`, `.topic_container`, `.search_container`, `.search_topic` do not exist in your html, will you please post your full code you tried?

Comment: What's in styles?

Comment: And I don't see any reason why something in your html would hide besides `.topic_container`, `.search_container` and `.search_topic`, which are not in your html code

Comment: In other words you hide nothing, Jon Snow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually in your JS-Code you are not targeting elements that are visible in your Html-Code. However you have forgotten the  "});" to close the "$(document).ready(function(){".

so just add this to the end, and it should fire normally.
Js should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search').click(function(){
    text = $('#search_word').val();
    $(".return").fadeIn('slow');
    $('.topic_retain:contains("'+text+'")').css("display", "block");
    $('.question_block:contains("'+text+'")').fadeIn();
    $('.topic_container').fadeOut();
    $('.search_container').fadeOut();
    $('.search_topic').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Hope it helps :)